# Regular expression to convert usernames into links like Twitter does

Tags: php, regex, twitter

in twitter
when you write @moustafa
will change to `<a href='user/moustafa'>@moustafa</a>`
now i want make the same thing
when write @moustafa + space its change @moustafa only

Comment: They actually change it to @<a href='user/moustafa'>moustafa</a>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One regular expression that could be used (shamelessly stolen from the [@anywhere javascript library](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#auto-linkify) mentioned in another answer) would be:

```
\B\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})
```

This looks for a non–word-boundary (to prevent `a@b` [i.e. emails] from matching) followed by `@`, then between one and 20 (inclusive) characters in that character class. Of course, the *anything-except-space* route, as in other answers; it depends very much on what values are to be (dis)allowed in the label part of the `@label`.

To use the highlighted regex in PHP, something like the following could be used to replace a string `$subject`.

```
$subject = 'Hello, @moustafa how are you today?';
echo preg_replace('/\B\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/', '<a href="user/$1">$0</a>', $subject);
```

The above outputs something like:

```
Hello, <a href="user/moustafa">@moustafa</a> how are you today?
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a regular expression that matches @username, where username doesn't have a space? You can use:

```
@[^ ]+
```

If you know the allowed characters in a username you can be more specific, like if they have to be alphanumeric:

```
@[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [@anywhere javascript library](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#auto-linkify) that Twitter have recently released?

Comment: It's a javascript library that you run on the webpage to do things like you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions in PHP are just Strings that start and end with the same character. By convention this character is /

So you can use something like this as an argument to any of the many php regular expression functions:

Not space:

```
"/[^ ]+/"
```

Alphanumeric only:

```
"/[A-Za-z0-9]+/"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that perform this selection and linking for you. Currently I know of Java, Ruby, and PHP libraries under mzsanford's Github account: http://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-rb