# How to select multiple texts with @ as the first letter of the text inside a line of texts?

Tags: php, explode

Okay, the header question may sound confusing, yeah, I too was confused. Anyway, what I wanted is this:
Say I have this line of text,

```
The quick brown @fox jumps @over the @lazy dog.
```

This line of text is a dynamically fetched 'single line' from the database, not an array of texts. Assuming the texts with first letter as '@' are links to a page or something, I want that I can specify on where to put my anchor tag, in my case, I want to put anchor tag on each of the texts starting with '@'.

I tried explode, but it seems explode is not the answer to this. Can someone help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: Once you've processed this line with PHP what do you want it to look like, what end-result are you looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to convert usernames into links like Twitter does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705769/regular-expression-to-convert-usernames-into-links-like-twitter-does)

Comment: @mario, thank you for letting me know but my problem's a bit different. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) for that, but a regex. To match multiple occurences, [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) is the deal.

```
preg_match_all('/@\w+/', $input, $matches);

        #        @   is the literal "@" character
        #    and \w+ matches consecutive letters
```

You certainy might want to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to transform them into links. Or better yet [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to move some logic into a handler function.

Comment: Agree 100% on the regex approach. Beat me to it!

Comment: Wow, this is new to me. But, I'm in a sh***y situation right now, I somehow understand the flow of your answer, but it seems I find it hard to implement. I searched a while ago for preg_match_all at php.net/manual, but can you please elaborate on what should I supposedly do? *feelsdumbrightnow

Comment: aw yeah, eventually I got it. Thanks guys. Now I'll be troubling myself with preg_replace now.

Comment: @CHiRiLo: The linked duplicate contained a similar method. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766158/php-to-replace-username-with-link-to-twitter-account

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to process the words that have a @ before...  It really depends on what you want to do:

```
//Store the string in a variable
$textVar = "The quick brown @fox jumps @over the @lazy dog.";

//Use explode to separate words
$words = explode(" ", $textVar);

//Check all the variables in the array, if the first character is a @
//keep it, else, unset it
foreach($words as $key=>$val) {
    if(substr($val, 0, 1) != "@") {
        unset($words[$key]);
    } else {
        $words[$key] = "<a href='#'>".$words[$key]."</a>";
    }
}

//You can now printout the array and you will get only the words that start with @
foreach($words as $word) {
    echo $word."<br>";
}
```

You could also keep the strings that dont have a @ and use an implode to put everything together:

```
//Store the string in a variable
$textVar = "The quick brown @fox jumps @over the @lazy dog.";

//Use explode to separate words
$words = explode(" ", $textVar);

//Check all the variables in the array, if the first character is a @
//keep it, else, unset it
foreach($words as $key=>$val) {
    if(substr($val, 0, 1) != "@") {
        //Do nothing
    } else {
        $words[$key] = "<a href='#'>".$words[$key]."</a>";
    }
}

//You can now printout the string
$words = implode($words, " ");
echo $words;
```